# Extract multiple patches around landmarks in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to extract multiple patches around a set of 2D landmarks in the same image using TensorFlow.

Given an input tensor of 2D landmarks of shape`[batch_size, num_landmarks, 2]` and an input image tensor of shape `[batch_size, num_rows, num_cols, num_channels]` I would like to return a tensor containing `[batch_size, num_landmarks, patch_rows, patch_cols, num_channels]`.

For now we can assume that `batch_size=1` and if so, the following code will do the above:

```
im = tf.tile(im, (num_landmarks, 1, 1, 1))
patches = tf.image.extract_glimpse(im, (patch_cols, patch_rows), landmarks, centered=False, normalized=False)
```

I basically repeat the input image as many times as I have landmarks and then extract the glimpses. This is of course insane, when I have a lot of landmarks, so I was wondering if there exists a better way.

EDIT:

I think `tf.gather_nd` could do the trick, so I'm working on building the indices I need to extract the patches.